# Internal redirect urls to external sites shows up on google

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo, anchor

I have a redirect URL for external links example would be `<a href="www.mysite.com/redirect?id=234gf34">click</a>` which does a great job. However, making a site search on google like this 'site:www.mysite.com' shows my redirect links, and clicking on them takes me directly to where its redirecting to.

Is there any way to stop google from using those specific links in their results?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please note that `www.mysite.com/redirect?id=234gf34` is _not_ a valid URL, it lacks the scheme (protocol). It _might_ work in some situations, depending on the software used, but that is more or less luck.

Comment: To answer your question it would be helpful if you would tell _how_ you redirect to the final URL.

Comment: I think you're looking for [nofollow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow).

Comment: http://www.robotstxt.org/ might help you

Comment: @arkascha The page 'redirect' picks up the id, gets the url from db and, updates the 'clicked' count and redirects using php header function. It was suggested to use robots.txt but im open to more suggestions

Comment: If I recall correctly, then google makes a difference depending on _how_ you redirect, using a temporary or a permanent redirection (302 versus 301). I'd expect this to be documented by google, you should take a look into their explanations about SEO.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a robots.txt file and place these 2 lines of text in it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /redirect
```

See the explanation here,
http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: Thanks @anddontcallmeshirley that seems like a great solution, was worries it might not work as expected!